# Adobe AIR file upload response data in complete handler is null while fiddler(web debugger) shows that json is returned as response

Tags: json, apache-flex, air, adobe, response

When uploading a file from adobe AIR to a backbone server, the response returned is not anyway accessible when using file.upload(request) function, while i can see json response in fiddler(web debugger and in task manager), also it was working fine when using URLLoader.load() instead of file.upload()

```
var url = "api url of backbone server ";
request = null;
file = null;

request = new air.URLRequest(url);
request.useCache = false;

var authorization = new air.URLRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);
var contentType = new air.URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
var Accept = new air.URLRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

request.requestHeaders.push(authorization);
request.requestHeaders.push(contentType);
request.requestHeaders.push(Accept);    

file = new air.File(path);
pathNative = file.nativePath;
var directory = getDirectoryFromPath(pathNative);

params = new air.URLVariables();
params.parent_id = directory.directory_id;
params.name = file.name;
request.data = params;
request.method = air.URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.contentType = 'multipart/form-data, boundary='+boundary;

var file = new air.File(path);
file.upload(request);
file.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, function(e){

    air.Introspector.Console.log(file);
    air.Introspector.Console.log(e);
    air.Introspector.Console.log(e.target.data);
});
```

This is the console for complete event as you can see returned data is null.
[see console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMO6d.png)
while in fiddler shows that json is returned.
[see fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xYRb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a known issue on iOS? Are you trying to do this from iOS?

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1720117?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: also all things works perfectly, file gets uploaded, request and response are also perfect as shown in debugger but somehow it is not consoled in COMPLETE handler nor in progress or error handler

Comment: which version of air?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Instead of using air.Event.COMPLETE, try to use air.DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA:

```
file.addEventListener(air.DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, function(e){

         air.Introspector.Console.log(e.data);

});
```